# Spring-Cloud-DataFlow-Stream Source not running as per cron setting but instead running only once

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have developed the Spring Cloud Data which I have Source -- Transform -- Sink, but the Source is not picking up every 3 minutes, i have this one as application.properties --> `poller.cron=1-59/2 * * * * *`

But it seem to be doing only once instead of running source to transform  to sink every 3 minutes. Any help is appreciate

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class FetchFromDbApplication {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FetchFromDbApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    CustomerService customerService;

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(
            value = Source.OUTPUT,
            poller = @Poller(cron = "${poller.cron}", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1")
    )
    public MessageSource<List<Customer>> processCustomer() { this one will run the query and fetch the customers to transform and then to sink}..
```